# "tooltip" prop missing from IconButton component in MaterialUI next

Tags: material-ui

I know MaterialUI next is still in alpha, but I noticed that the tooltip prop that is available in the current stable release of MUI is not present in "next" version. Is that because that feature just hasn't been implemented yet, or is that feature being removed from future releases?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

material-ui-next has a dedicated tooltip component on its own

Here's how to use it:

```js
<Tooltip id="tooltip-fab" title="Add">
  <Button variant="fab" color="primary" aria-label="Add" className={classes.fab}>
    <AddIcon />
  </Button>
</Tooltip>
```

See documentation for more detail
https://material-ui-next.com/api/tooltip/

Comment: Thanks. I asked this question almost a year ago, and at that time, they hadn't gotten to the tooltip component. Glad to see they've done it now, though.